# How to retrieve each line of a text file in order [python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to compare two txt files and find the new lines from one file and write them into a new file.

I noticed that the new lines are written in a different order every time I run the program. Is there a way to preserve the original order?

I noticed that the disorder stems from `read().splitlines()` on lines 2 and 3.

My code:

```
with open("C:/Temp/1_attlog.dat", "r") as f1, open("C:/Temp/attlog.dat","r") as f2, open("C:/Temp/attlog_new.dat", "w") as n:
f_a = set(f1.read().splitlines())
f_b = set(f2.read().splitlines())
for line in f_a:
    count_line += 1
    if line not in f_b:
        print(line)
        count_new_lines += 1
        n.writelines(line)
```

Comment: You put the lines in a `set`. Sets are unordered containers.

Comment: As khelwood said "set" doesn't keep order, You can use Orderedset: https://pypi.org/project/orderedset/

Comment: Is there any benefit to using an OrderedSet instead of a List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From The python documentation for [**Set**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> A set is an **unordered** collection with no duplicate elements.

When you save each line into a set the order in which the items are retrieved is not guaranteed to be the same as when they went in.

A better choice might be to use a [**List**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and in fact, the [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) function already returns a list.

You should be able to fix your code by simply removing `set(...)` from line 2.

```
with open("C:/Temp/1_attlog.dat", "r") as f1, open("C:/Temp/attlog.dat","r") as f2, open("C:/Temp/attlog_new.dat", "w") as n:
    f_a = f1.read().splitlines() # No more set
    f_b = set(f2.read().splitlines())
    for line in f_a:
        count_line += 1
        if line not in f_b:
            print(line)
            count_new_lines += 1
            n.writelines(line)
```